# SQL code for search option in a php web page

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to write the search.php file for an online library web page. This is what I have done , I can search books by titles ,but I also want to search them by author or description

```
if (isset($_GET['str'])) {
$category = htmlspecialchars($_GET['str']);
$qlib = 'SELECT * FROM book_description JOIN book_class ON book_class.series = book_description.series WHERE book_description.title LIKE "%'.$category.'%"'
```

Comment: Have you tried adding those to your `WHERE` clause?  Also, be aware that your code is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using. `htmlspecialchars` provides *zero* SQL injection protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM book_description 
JOIN book_class ON book_class.series = book_description.series 
WHERE book_description.title LIKE "%'.$category.'%"'
and (or) book_description.author like "%'.$author.'%"'
... 
and so on
```

Hope it helps! You can use `and` or `or` in where clause

Comment: This urgently needs placeholder values. Using more string concatenation is making it worse.